# Add a link as an answer to myself

Tags: support, answers, self-answer, hyperlinks

I asked a question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/209191/186520) a couple of days ago and I just found an excellent video on YouTube (Computerphile channel) that has a direct connection with the code I posted in my question, and could help beginners like me understanding encryption better.

Is it ok :

1. To post an external link?
2. To post it as an answer to my question with a brief description of the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to post external links with a description of the contents, but the description is important because sometimes external links become 404s, and the answer becomes useless if it didn't summarise the external content.

Answer (score 2):

All answers should contain at least one insightful remark about the code. So if you propose to post an answer which only contains a link, a description/summary and a "this is relevant to understand encryption" remark, you have failed to write a proper answer and it may be flagged/removed as such.

You could post is as supplement to an answer, but it doesn't substitute an answer. If you don't want to write an answer but want to link to the video anyway, edit it into your question instead.